# NVIDIA drivers 410 break Ubuntu 18.04 with GTX 1050

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, 18.04, graphics

I'm having troubles installing NVIDIA drivers 410 on my Ubuntu 18.04 machine.

I tried installing them via driver manager and it didn't work, so I tried installing them via runfile and it didn't work either.

Searching on the forums I've seen someone who solved by adding `nvidia-drm.modeset=1` to `/etc/default/grub`, nothing changed.

The TTY1 gets stuck always with the drivers. If I boot with just `nomodeset` I can access others TTY and use the bash (then purge nvidia* and use Noveau).

I've tried booting `nvidia-drm.modeset=1` with both `quiet splash` and `nomodeset` and it isn't working.

Any suggestion?

Comment: What kind of error did you get with the GUI installer? You can also try `sudo apt install nvidia-current`

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I've managed to solve the problem on my own. Steps:

**1 Install drivers**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-396
```

**2) edit GRUB**

```
nano /etc/default/grub
```

Edit `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` into

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nvidia-drm.modeset=1"
```

Then:

```
sudo update-grub
```

**3) edit GDM settings**

```
sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

Remove the `#` from `# WaylandEnable=false`

Hope this will help someone.

Comment: I tried this, and I can get to the LUKS decryption screen, albeit with the wrong native resolution, then I proceed to the Ubuntu logo, but it stops loading at three of five dots.

Comment: I think this could be an issue of Gnome and nVidia. I've tried using Kubuntu (same as Ubuntu, but with KDE) and it has no problem even with LUKS.